# Creating New Dataframes from Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to create 2 separate data frames from the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

sport = ('basketball','volleyball','football')
science = ('biology','chemistry','physics')

sportdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name','Interest'])
sciencedf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name','Interest'])

data = [['tom', 'volleyball'], ['nick', 'chemistry'], ['juli', 'physics']] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Interest'])

s = []
q = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,"Interest"] in sport:
        s.append(df.loc[i,"Name"])
        s.append(df.loc[i,"Interest"])
        df_length = len(s)
        sportdf.loc[df_length] = s
        print(df)
    else:
        q.append(df.loc[i,"Name"])
        q.append(df.loc[i,"Interest"])
        df_length = len(q)
        #sciencedf.loc[df_length] = q
```

The expected output is the sportdf data frame will have one row which is 'tom' and 'volleyball' and the sciencedf to be 'nick' 'chemistry' and 'juli' 'physics'.

However in the code above I am getting the sportdf created successfully but the sciencedf is not created because the list q is ['nick','chemistry','juli','physics]. I can split this in other ways then add but I feel like I'm making this 100x harder than it actually is. To summarize:

```
for every row in df:
if the cell of the 'Interest' column is in the sport tuple:
add the row to the sportdf
if it is not (elif):
add the row to the sciencedf
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas isin function is the solution : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Code below would help you

```
import pandas as pd

sport = ('basketball','volleyball','football')
science = ('biology','chemistry','physics')
data = [['tom', 'volleyball'], ['nick', 'chemistry'], ['juli', 'physics']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Interest'])

# just two lines of isin condition
sciencedf = df.loc[df['Interest'].isin(science)]
sprotdf = df.loc[df['Interest'].isin(sport)]

print(sciencedf)
print(sprotdf)
```

Output:

```
   Name   Interest
1  nick  chemistry
2  juli    physics
 
 Name    Interest
0  tom  volleyball
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your info:

```
import pandas as pd

sport = ('basketball','volleyball','football')
science = ('biology','chemistry','physics')

data = [['tom', 'volleyball'], ['nick', 'chemistry'], ['juli', 'physics']]
```

Then you can use list comprehensions with an if clause to build the data you need for each dataframe:

```
  
sportdata = [ [name, interest] for name, interest in data if interest in sport]
sciencedata = [ [name, interest] for name, interest in data if interest in science]
```

After that, you can build each dataframe as usual:

```
sportdf = pd.DataFrame(sportdata, columns = ['Name', 'Interest'])
sciencedf = pd.DataFrame(sciencedata, columns = ['Name', 'Interest'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-query-method) method, the next solution was tested using Python 3.7. I think this solution is more legible.

```
import pandas as pd
sport = ('basketball','volleyball','football')
science = ('biology','chemistry','physics')

sportdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name','Interest'])
sciencedf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name','Interest'])

data = [['tom', 'volleyball'], ['nick', 'chemistry'], ['juli', 'physics']] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Interest'])

# Only two lines
sportdf = df.query(f"Interest == {sport}")
sciencedf = df.query(f"Interest == {science}")

print(sportdf)
print(sciencedf)
```

Output:

```
    Name    Interest
0   tom volleyball

    Name    Interest
1   nick    chemistry
2   juli    physics
```